# windows10のコマンドプロンプトで数字の1が表示される

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

windows10のコマンドプロンプトで質問です。

```
dir > tmp.txt
```

という内容のバッチファイルを作成し、test.bat と名前をつけます。
これをコマンドプロンプトで実行すると、

> D:\>test
>
> D:\>dir  1>tmp.txt

と表示され、リダイレクト記号の前に半角の"1"が表示されます。
また、リダイレクト記号のあとにあった半角スペースは消えています。
tmp.txtの内容は問題ありません。

なぜバッチファイルの内容と違う命令が出力されてしまうのでしょうか。
この1は標準出力STDOUTのことなのでしょうか。
バッチファイルは S-JIS、コマンドプロンプトも CP932 です。

Comment: 参考までに、[Batch files - How To ... Display and Redirect Output](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_redirection.php) には `When we use > to redirect Standard Output, CMD.EXE interprets this as 1>, as can be seen by writing and running ...` と書かれています。

Comment: 参考になる、というよりは解説そのもののサイトありがとうございました。私もこのようなサイトをピンポイントで探せるスキルを身につけたいです。

Comment: google で検索ワードを `cmd.exe redirect standard output "1>"` としました。ただ、わざわざ `1>` と表示する理由については分かりませんでした(標準出力であることを強調しているのかもしれませんが…)。

Answer (score 2):

[Batch files - How To ... Display and Redirect Output](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_redirection.php) には以下のように書かれています。

> When we use > to redirect Standard Output, CMD.EXE interprets this as 1>, as can be seen by writing and running ...

---

<sup>この投稿は @metropolis さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/33693/#comment33153_33693)などを元に編集し、[コミュニティWiki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1583)として投稿しました。</sup>